# Using Facebook access tokens obtained in mobile app to access ASP.Net WebAPI2 controller actions

Tags: asp.net, facebook, cordova, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

### Setup

**Client:** mobile app built on Cordova
**Backend:** ASP.net WebAPI2 (based on the standard template) configured with facebook login provider.

### Problem

Having authenticated the user in the mobile app and received a Facebook access token, I pass this in subsequent requests as an HTTP header ("Authorization: Bearer "). This returns status 401 Unauthorized.

### Questions

What am i missing here? How can i access the WebAPI controller actions based on the Facebook access token obtained on the mobile device?

On a high level, what i'm trying to achieve is this:

1. User opens mobile app and authenticates with Facebook
2. If user is not registered as a local user, he must choose a username to complete the registration
3. User is registered and can access API

Comment: Any news on this one?

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem and I found a really good solution here: http://codetrixstudio.com/mvc-web-api-facebook-sdk/

The WebApi web site can't understand the access token provided by Facebook. I guess it's because it hasn't been issued by itself (LOCAL AUTHORITY) but by an external provider. The approach explained in the link above is based on validating the token given by Facebook using it's API and recreating the access token.

So, you'll need some additional steps to achieve your goal.

The external providers have API so you can get information. For example, the https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={0} can be used to check if the token is valid. On the server side, you'll need to make a https web request to this URL passing the token (and the secret app as a proof, if the app is configured to ask it in Facebook).

Given the token is ok, you'll create an identity (ClaimsIdentity) using the information you've got at the API (id and username, for example). This identity will be needed to make an instance of the AuthenticationTicket class so you'll be able to issue a new access token for your Cordova app. Use this new bearer access token in the Authorization header of your https calls and your WebApi will recognized it as valid calls.

Ps. The good thing here is that you can set the token's expiration.

Comment: Great solution in that link. Thanks for saving my day !

Answer (score 1):

Since API's are stateless, there are multiple ways to secure it.  In this case the mobile app has authenticated the user, but the API has not.

1. You can register the user's email and facebook ID into the database using a anonymous route.  this can serve as both the login and register technically.  (you could secure it with a clientid via OAuth if you don't want it fully open) along with thier current token.   You verify the user against the facebook API on the server before registering of course just in case.
2. Create a custom route handler to secure the account controller or any other routes.   The custom route handler would check the database for the current FB token and fb ID combo as well as token expire time, since you don't want to keep authenticating if it's expired.

Facebook has two types of tokens.

A Short lived token, initially created when you login and a long term token that lasts up to 60 days vs 1-2 hours.

for the api side, i suggest sticking to the short lived token and re-authenticate once expired but thats up to you.

You should grab a facebook SDK of your choice to verify and pull account info.

Example Secured Route:

```
     public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
     {
         config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
             name: "routename",
             routeTemplate: "account",
             constraints: null,
             handler: new CustomFBHandler()
                 {
                     InnerHandler = new HttpControllerDispatcher(config)
                 },
             defaults: new {controller = "default"}
             ); 
            }
```

Custom Handler:  (note that you should pass any needed dependancies in the construtor)

```
  public class CustomHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {        
        public CustomHandler()        
        {
        }

        protected async Task<bool> IsAuthenticated(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage)
        {

            //Authenticate FB User Info HERE Against the Registered/logged in user.... 



        }

        protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            bool isAuthenticated = false;

            try
            {                
                isAuthenticated = await IsAuthenticated(request);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                var response = request
                            .CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new { status = new { code = 333, error = true, message = e.Message } }, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
                response.Headers.WwwAuthenticate.Add(new AuthenticationHeaderValue(Configuration.AuthenticationScheme));                
                return response;
            }



            if (!isAuthenticated)
            {                
                var response = request
                              .CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,new {status=new{code=1,error=true,message="Authorization Failed"}},new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
                                response.Headers.WwwAuthenticate.Add(new AuthenticationHeaderValue(Configuration.AuthenticationScheme));
                return response;
            }

            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

You should send the FB Token and Facebook user id in the Headers.  Once authenticated you can use the token/id to pull the user info you need from the database.